# Remove all the '#' from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have tried all kinds of different things when it comes to this. How do I just remove all the # from this list that I created?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('http://www.demodms.com/annuity', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
lists = []

for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
    lists.append(anchor['href'])

lists.remove('#')


print(lists)
```

Comment: Please just show your `lists` data so we can  manipulate it directly without importing and downloading external data.  BeautifulSoup and Requests have nothing to do with the actual issue at hand.

Comment: This will remove every string with the value `#` from the list named `lists`, which is exactly what you asked for. Are you trying to do something different, like remove every `#` from every string in that list? Or truncate every string at the first `#`, removing everything after it? Or…? If so, you have to tell us what you actually want to do. It may be easier to give us a [mcve] with sample input and desired output instead of trying to explain it.

Comment: Also, is there a reason this is called `lists`? That implies that it's going to be a list of lists, or something like that, but from your code, it looks like it's going to be a list of strings. Obviously, the right thing to do for a list of strings isn't going to the same as the right thing to do for a list of lists of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.remove(value)` only removes the first occurrence.  You can use a loop to keep removing duplicate values until there are none left:

```
while '#' in lists:
    lists.remove('#')
```

Perhaps a better solution is to not add unwanted values in the first place:

```
for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
    if anchor['href'] != '#':
        lists.append(anchor['href'])
```

Comment: I liked the second solution you offered. It worked better and logically would be cleaner than making another loop that just would be redundant. Thanks for this feedback.

Comment: The while loop that you have above works great just for one item, but if I try to remove '#' or '/events/' I keep getting an error. What is the best way to loop through the entire list and remove them in one swipe vs making a loop for each set of items I want to remove? I've tried using `while '#' or '/events/'` and `while '#' and '/events/'` but neither work.

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish if you just want to remove all the instances of multiple strings: use replace as in my answer or alter it to do a double remove in the while loop in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Or a list comprehension:

```
print([i for i in lists if i != '#'])
```

Or `filter`:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x!='#',lists)))
```

Also as John Gordon says, even easier:

```
for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
    if anchor['href'] != '#':
        lists.append(anchor['href'])
```

Or a list comprehension again:

```
lists = [anchor['href'] for anchor in soup.find_all("a") if anchor['href'] != '#']
```

See [List comprehnsions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

See [Map, Filter, and Reduce](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

One quick method for removing all instances of a character is the string method [replace](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

Assuming a list like this, updated based on your feedback. Let's say remove all `#` and `*` in strings, you just need to use replace twice:

```
a = ['#AA#andRou**nds', '#abcDrat', '#ad**dchat', '#advchat', '#Aet#', '#A#Cha#t', 
    '#An#Q', '#an#alk', '#AskAvail#', '#ASP#hat', '#AT#lk', 
    '#aut#chat', '#AX###hat', '#aya#m', '#*bc*#c#', '#bc#w', '#bioet##hx']

a = [e.replace("#", "").replace("*", "") for e in a]
print(a)
```

This will loop through each element of your list using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and remove all instances of `#` in each string. You can send the optional count if you want to limit the number of hashtags replaced (change to `e.replace("#", "", 1)` if you only wanted to remove the first instance for example).